# How come onclick event gets fired by child nodes of button tag in google chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, button

The situation:

1. Create button object with document.createElement
2. Directly assign onclick event, e.g: button.onclick = showResult;
3. Modify button innerHtml/append img node (I've tried both), to put inside it a magnifying glass png icon.
4. Define showResult function, which receives evt parameter, then try to get the target tagName attribute, but when you click over the icon, it returns 'IMG' instead 'BUTTON'

Here's the snippet:

```
td = document.createElement( 'td' );
btn = document.createElement( 'button' );
btn.type = "button";
btn.onclick = showResults;
btn.innerHTML = '<img src="../img/mag.png" />';
td.appendChild( btn );
```

And the function

```
function showResults( evt ) {
    console.log( evt.target.src );
}
```

I fixed this using this conditional:

```
var btn = evt.target == 'BUTTON' ? evt.target : evt.target.parentNode;
```

But I really do not like it, is there a workaround or something about this behavior, that you can point my eyes to?.

Comment: That is how [event bubbling/propagation](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html) works.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just put the image as a background of the button?

Comment: This might be interesting: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.currentTarget

Comment: @epascarello I will review it, and I thought it has anything to do with that.  It only happens with google chrome.

I do not like the way google chrome (webkit) deals with this, but if that's the specification on this behavior that is designed for dom, nothing else to do.  Sometimes I believe webkit is some kind of spoiled child, but reading every document regarding its behavior, most of the times I realize is mozilla who spoils us!

Comment: @GarethCornish, I like that idea, but the exercise must be done without CSS.

Comment: @Teemu Thank you, the answer was given by Kohver too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this can help you

```
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
btn.onclick = function(e) {
    clickedButton = e.currentTarget;
    console.log(clickedButton);
}​
```

Check the example http://jsfiddle.net/Kohver/RD3Zg/

Comment: Thank you Kohver, I'll keep it in mind, to keep using the currentTarget attribute.